# Change Fusioncharts from flash to pureJS

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Several years ago i started a website that's quite popular. It has been using FusionCharts Free v2 to show statistics on the website. but as we are nearing EOL on flash is there some way i can change FusionCharts from using SWF/Flash into using JS? if so, how? i did not setup the statistics part so i have no clue fusioncharts work.

I have added an example from my stats.php file and a pastebin further down  just to show you how it looks.

```
  <?php
                /* pie chart  */
                $dataForPie = $db->getRows("SELECT os, COUNT(id) AS total FROM stats WHERE page_title = '" . $shortUrlObj->id . "' GROUP BY os ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 20");

                $strXML = "";
                $strXML .= "<graph animation='1' showValues='0' showNames='1' pieRadius='95' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0' baseFont='Arial' baseFontSize='10'>";
                foreach ($dataForPie AS $dataRow)
                {
                    $position = rand(0, COUNT($colours) - 1);
                    $strXML .= "<set name='" . UCWords($dataRow['os']) . "' value='" . $dataRow['total'] . "' color='" . $colours[$position] . "'/>";
                }
                $strXML .= "</graph>";

                echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", $strXML, "statusPie", 830, 250);
                ?>
```

**Charts used in *stats.php* that i could find**

Pastebin if anyone wanna look: https://pastebin.com/469BpG3G

1: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Column2D.swf?noCache=" . microtime(true), "", $strXML, "hourChart", 890, 350);`

2: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Column2D.swf?noCache=" . microtime(true), "", $strXML, "weekChart", 890, 350);`

3: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Column2D.swf?noCache=" . microtime(true), "", $strXML, "monthChart", 890, 350);`

4: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Column2D.swf?noCache=" . microtime(true), "", $strXML, "yearChart", 890, 350);`

5: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", $strXML, "statusPie", 830, 250);`

6: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", $strXML, "statusPie", 830, 250);`

7: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", $strXML, "statusPie", 830, 250);`

8: `echo renderChartHTML("js/fusionCharts/Charts/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", $strXML, "statusPie", 830, 250);`

Comment: What kind of chart do you want? lines? area? pie? bar? histogram? scatter?...

Comment: I updated my post with all the different charts used if that helps ?

Comment: FusionCharts flash version is now deprecated, it now renders in pure javascript, please upgrade to the latest version 3.15.1-sr.1 for all the latest fixes and improvements, you can download it from here - https://www.fusioncharts.com/download

For rendering charts in PHP check this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/php/your-first-chart-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the document from flash to Javascript -

Also refer the doc using clone() -

Sample code -

```
// Fetch the object reference of the Flash-rendered chart.
var myFlashChart = FusionCharts('my-chart-id');
// Clone the Flash chart as JS chart.
var myJSChart = myFlashChart.clone({
renderer: 'javascript'
});
// For our case, we do not need the Flash chart anymore. Hence we delete it
// from memory.
myFlashChart.dispose();
myFlashChart = undefined;
// Render the newly cloned chart at the same place where the original chart
// was rendered.
myJSChart.render();
The above code shows how an existing FusionCharts object is cloned and then re-rendered. While cloning, we provide the overriding parameter that instructs to override the 'renderer' of the existing chart object with the new value we provided. Here, you can also override other parameters.

For ease of use, we pack the above set of codes within an easy-to-use function.
/**
* This function adds the ability to all FusionCharts instance objects to
* switch between Flash and JavaScript based rendering.
* @id: FusionCharts.prototype.switchRenderer
*
* @param {string} renderer optionally specifies which renderer has to be used.
* By default, it is set to Flash if current renderer is JavaScript and
* vice-versa.
*
* @type FusionCharts
* @return A new FusionCharts object whose renderer has been switched from
* Flash to JavaScript or vice-versa.
*
* @example
* var myChart = FusionCharts('my-chart-id');
* myChart = myChart.switchRenderer();
*/
FusionCharts.prototype.switchRenderer = function (renderer) {
// Get the parameters needed to clone the chart.
// Doing this in order to retain same chart id.
var newChartParams = this.clone({
renderer: renderer ||
(this.options.renderer.toLowerCase() === 'flash' ?
'javascript' : 'flash'),
id: this.id    }, true),
// Keep track whether the chart is currently in a rendered state or not.
wasRendered = this.isActive(), newChart;
// Delete the existing chart.
this.dispose();
// Create new chart with same ID as existing.
newChart = new FusionCharts(newChartParams);
// If the chart was previously in a rendered state, then render the chart.
if (wasRendered) {
newChart.render();
}
// Create and render the new chart.
return newChart;
};
```

To know more about about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/toggle-between-flash-and-javascript-charts-using-clone-method/